# Запрос с предикатом BETWEEN и NULL

Tags: sql

Всем доброго времени, не могу понять как правильно написать запрос с between и null
Вот мой код

```
WITH a(a) AS (
VALUES 1, 2, 3, 4, NULL) 
SELECT 
        a 
FROM 
        a 
WHERE 
        a BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

Результат будет таким

```
+---+
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
+---+
```

Как написать запрос что бы в конце был еще NULL, обязательно используя BETWEEN

```
+---+
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
|null|
+---+
```

Comment: В  условие добавить or a is null

Comment: Огроменное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH a(a) AS (VALUES 1, 2, 3, 4, NULL) 
SELECT a 
FROM a 
WHERE a BETWEEN 2 AND 4
    OR a IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE COALESCE(a, 2) BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

Можно при помощи `COALESCE` заменить `NULL` на значение из диапазона, например на одно из крайних значений.